# XSLT group by name and sum values

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, grouping

INPUT

```
<root>
<TL>
    <msg>
        <output_getquerydata>
            <queries>
                <query name="q1">
                    <parameters>
                        <parameter name="id">906OREA</parameter>
                    </parameters>
                    <queryErrors/>
                    <queryResults>
                        <record>
                            <column name="actionState">sdss</column>
                        </record>
                    </queryResults>
                </query>
                <query name="q2">
                    <parameters>
                        <parameter name="resCode">CTL-3819</parameter>
                        <parameter name="prodCode">89CMID</parameter>
                    </parameters>
                    <queryErrors/>
                    <queryResults>
                        <record id="1">
                            <column name="resource_externalId">CTL-000002</column>
                            <column name="compartmentCode">CTL-3819-01</column>
                            <column name="ExternalProductId"/>
                        </record>
                        <record id="2">
                            <column name="resource_externalId">CTL-000002</column>
                            <column name="compartmentCode">CTL-3819-02</column>
                            <column name="ExternalProductId"/>
                        </record>
                        <record id="3">
                            <column name="resource_externalId"/>
                            <column name="compartmentCode"/>
                            <column name="position"/>
                            <column name="ExternalProductId">316442</column>
                        </record>
                    </queryResults>
                </query>
                <query name="q2">
                    <parameters>
                        <parameter name="resCode">CTL-3819</parameter>
                        <parameter name="prodCode">91VPRM</parameter>
                    </parameters>
                    <queryErrors/>
                    <queryResults>
                        <record id="1">
                            <column name="resource_externalId">CTL-000002</column>
                            <column name="compartmentCode">CTL-3819-01</column>
                            <column name="position">1</column>
                            <column name="ExternalProductId"/>
                        </record>
                        <record id="2">
                            <column name="resource_externalId"/>
                            <column name="compartmentCode"/>
                            <column name="position"/>
                            <column name="ExternalProductId">316495</column>
                        </record>
                    </queryResults>
                </query>
            </queries>
        </output_getquerydata>
    </msg>
    <TL>
        <id>65004</id>
        <ArticleNr>89CMID</ArticleNr>
        <Gross>2700</Gross>
    </TL>
    <TL>
        <id>65005</id>
        <ArticleNr>89CMID</ArticleNr>
        <Gross>1700</Gross>
        <BOLNumber>18117</BOLNumber>
    </TL>
    <TL>
        <id>65006</id>
        <ArticleNr>89CMID</ArticleNr>
        <Gross>2100</Gross>
        <BOLNumber>18117</BOLNumber>
    </TL>
    <TL>
        <id>65007</id>
        <ArticleNr>91VPRM</ArticleNr>
        <Gross>500</Gross>
        <BOLNumber>18117</BOLNumber>
    </TL>
</TL>
</root>
```

XSL:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:key name="Article" match="TL" use="./ArticleNr"/>
<xsl:key name="prod" match="query[@name='q2']/queryResults/record" use="../../parameters/parameter[@name='prodCode']"/>
<xsl:template match="root">
    <msglist>
        <xsl:for-each select="./TL[./msg/output_getquerydata/queries/query/queryResults/record/column[@name='actionState'] !='finished'] ">
            <xsl:variable name="distinctArticle" select="//TL[string(ArticleNr)][count(. | key('Article',ArticleNr)[1]) = 1]"/>
            <msg>
                <CMT>
                    <m>
                        <a>
                            <AP>
                                <xsl:variable name="position">
                                    <!--variable to concatenate all products -->
                                    <xsl:for-each select="$distinctArticle">
                                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="concat(key('prod', .//ArticleNr)/column[@name='ExternalProductId'][. != ''],';')"/>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:for-each select="TL[generate-id() = 
                   generate-id(key('Article', .//ArticleNr)[1])]">
                                    <grossVolume>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(concat(.,';'))"/>
                                    </grossVolume>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <product>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="substring($position, string-length($position))=';'">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="substring($position, 1, string-length($position)-1)"/>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$position"/>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </product>
                            </AP>
                        </a>
                    </m>
                </CMT>
            </msg>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </msglist>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is almost good. The thing is I need in the grossVolume node to have the sum of all "Gross" nodes for the same ArticleNr.
SO, my output would be:

```
 <grossVolume>6500;500</grossVolume>
 <product>316442;316495</product>
```

Because for ArticleNr - 89CMID -, we have the sum values in gross 2700+1700+2100=6500.

Basically, for all "ArticleNr" nodes that have the same values, I need to sum all the numbers from their respective "Gross" nodes, and then produce an output where we concatenate these sums.
For the Product node output, I concatenate the required values, and it works, I need to have that similar information in the grossVolume node also.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do a `sum()` and `concat()` in the same instruction as it would throw an error for string and number combination. The sum will have to be stored in a local variable and then used to concatenate with other sums to form the value of `<grossVolume>`.

Please change the `for-each` loop for `TL`

```
<xsl:for-each select="TL[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Article', .//ArticleNr)[1])]">
    <grossVolume>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(concat(.,';'))"/>
    </grossVolume>
</xsl:for-each>
```

to the below snippet

```
<grossVolume>
    <xsl:for-each select="TL[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Article', ./ArticleNr)[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="sumGross" select="sum(key('Article', ./ArticleNr)/Gross)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$sumGross" />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="';'" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</grossVolume>
```

Output

```
<grossVolume>6500;500</grossVolume>
```